# Count points that are within certain radius within a polygon

Tags: postgis, php

I have 4 table, I want to count police that are within 5km of a point (dam), schools and clinics within 3km same dam. So far I do get the results if I'm focusing on one table

```
$str = pg_query($conn, "SELECT count(a.geom) as health c.name as names FROM health as a dams as c WHERE ST_DWithin(a.geom, '$geoms', 3000, true) AND c.name = '$names' GROUP BY c.name ORDER BY c.name") or die ("Data loading failed: ".pg_last_error());
```

..but if I get more tables I get a a timeout.
I am looking for something like this...

```
Dam        Police     Health     Schools
Orange       3         12          26
```

Please assist